# Split large XML into multiple files

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I just wondering how can I split a large XML output of Nokogiri

For example, I filled up `Nokogiri::XML` with data and now I want to store all this data in separate files, each no larger than 10MB.

**Edit from comment**: We don't want to divide in the middle of tag, we want to replicate xml header in every file, there must be something in methods of Nokogiri.

Comment: This sounds like a good question, but you need to be more explicit in your requirements, preferably with sample input and output. If you have `<root><p>18MB of text</p></root>` what should the result be? How about for `<root><a><b>6MB</b><b>6MB</b><b>6MB</b></a></root>`? How about for `<root><a><b>4MB</b><b>4MB</b></a><c>4MB</c></root>`?

Comment: This isn't something that Nokogiri would be expected to know how to do; Nokogiri generates XML that you tell it to create. You, as the developer, are expected to know how much data you are generating, and then take steps to break that data into manageable chunks before generating the XML. That holds true whether you are creating XML with Nokogiri, or generating YAML, JSON or email messages with their appropriate generators.

Comment: One more particularly-pathological case: What should the output be for "<r a='1' b='2' c='3' ... aa='27' ab='28' ... />" and so on until you have multiple megabytes worth of attributes?

Comment: I need all this stuf to make sitemap. So break data only on <url> tag, and another problem is to add xml header to every sitemap* file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have some xml:

```
xml = '<foo><child num="1"/><child num="2"/><child num="3"/></foo>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

And you want to break up ranges of child nodes and save them separately without losing the heirarchy. You could do something like:

```
[0..0, 1..1, 2..2].each do |range|
    c = doc.clone
    (c.xpath('/foo/child') - c.xpath('/foo/child')[range]).remove #remove nodes not in range
    File.open("#{range.first}.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(c.to_s) }
end
```

Comment: great! can I do it simpler? For example, nokogiri object (sitemap) contains of huge number of <url>*</url> I need to do something like **each** on this object, on every run we count number of bytes

Answer (score -1):

How about using of this simple snippet:

```
def split_by_size(text, size = 10 * 1024 * 1024)
  text.scan /.{1, #{size}}/
end

split_by_size("12345" * 2, 3)  # => ["123", "451", "234", "5"]
```

You can use this array of chunks for saving them into separate files.

Comment: good, but doesn't appropriate for XML, we don't want to divide in the middle of tag, we want to replicate xml header in every file, there must be something in methods of nokogiri

Comment: This would seriously break an XML file.